# ES6/TS: Object destructuring in function call

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

**What would be a witty ES6+/TS shorthand to achieve object destructuring in a function call ?**

Let's assume a Javascript function that is widely used and cannot have its signature changed

```
const foo = (b, a) => console.log(b, a);
foo(66,55);                  // 66, 55
```

And an object that is used to supply values for call parameters

```
const o = {a: 55, b: 66 };
foo(o.b, o.a);               // 66, 55       <-- can we find a short-hand ?
```

Some calls not hitting the target

```
    foo(...Object.values(o)) // 55, 66 (no, JS object keys are unordered by definition)
    foo(...o);               // TypeError (short, but not valid, illustration only)
    foo(({b, a} = o));       // {a: 55, b: 66} undefined (no error, but we want 66, 55)
```

Comment: You can’t match object properties to positional parameters, since object order is undefined.

Comment: You can't do that. Javascript doesnot support the named parameters.

Comment: @deceze, true, I have marked it. Do you have different approach than the "traditional" (foo(o.b, o.a) in these situations ?

Comment: Nope, what you’re doing is very much how it’s done.

Comment: @Maheer Ali, yes, with named params there would be a short-cut. Do you use another approach than foo(o.b, o.a) ?

Comment: using `default parameters`, allow named parameters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: @naga - elixir - jar, can you give an example (the function signature cannot be altered by the question definition)

Comment: Still, I don't think you can

Comment: @zaggi You need to create a wrapper function and use `Function.toString` and then take out the arguments and that will be so hard. Simple way is that use object as parameter `const foo = ({b, a}) => console.log(b, a);` pass object instead of `foo(66,55);  `

Comment: `foo(...["b", "a"].map(p => o[p]))` would do it. But unless your parameter list is huge, or the properties are dynamically chosen, `foo(o.b, o.a)` is the simple and preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the signatur of the function, 
then you have to call it with each argument in the correct order.

And that is not possible for object deconstruction since a map dont has any order.

You can do something like that with **apply**:

```js
foo.apply(null, Object.values(o));
```

But you are not guaranteed the order of the values.

```js
function foo(a,b){return a*b-a}
foo(3,1) // => 0
foo(1,3) // => 2
var o1 = {a:3,b:1}
foo.apply(null,Object.values(o1)) // => 2
var o2 = {b:3, a:1}
foo.apply(null,Object.values(o2)) // => 0
```

So there are not any *witty* way to do it.